# Conditional searching which omits NA values

Tags: r, subset, conditional-statements

I'm doing a conditional search of part of a dataset that has multiple NA values within each row.

Something like this (a preview)..

```
        time1 time2 time3 time4 slice1 slice2 slice3 slice4
pt1    1      3     NA    NA    NA     1      3      5
pt2    NA     1     3     5     5      2      2      4
```

I want to do some conditional searching which applies a condition (comparing whether one column within a row is larger than another) for each row. I want to find all the rows (pt's) where a variable column (e.g. time1) is smaller than the corresponding column (e.g. slice 1).

```
all.smaller<-subset(patientdata, time1>slice1 & time2>slice2 & time3>slice3 & time4>slice4, na.rm=TRUE, select=c(1))
```

When I use this code (on a larger expanded table of this format), it only returns the rows without any NAs, where all the values are added in. This makes sense given the use of '&'.

My question is: Is there a way to find which rows fit my conditional search that ignores the NA's but only returns the rows where in all the column variables where values are provided, it searches whether time1>slice1, time2>slice2 etc.?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that takes a boolean (possibly `NA`) and maps it to `TRUE` if it is `NA` and its value otherwise.

```
na.true <- function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), TRUE, x)
```

You can then replace your subset with

```
na.true(time1 > slice1) & na.true(time2 > slice2) & na.true(time3 > slice3) & na.true(time4 > slice4)
```

Comment: after running this, I get an "Error in is.na(patiendata, TRUE, patientdata): 3 arguments passed to 'is.na' which requires 1".

'code' all.smaller<-subset(patientdata,na.true(time1>slice1)&na.true(time2>slice2)&na.true(time3>slice3)&na.true(time4>slice4),select=c(1))

Do you know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, I realized what I did wrong - I should just copy the first part of your code as is (I mistook x as the dataframe). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
n=1:4
cond <- paste0('((is.na(time',n,')|is.na(slice',n,'))|(time',n,'>slice',n,'))')
conds <- paste(cond, collapse=' & ')
all.smaller <- subset( patientdata, eval(parse(text=conds)) )
```

Essentially this checks if either time or slice are NA and forces a TRUE, and if not, check whether time is greater than slice. (Individually for each index.) It becomes clearer if you print out `conds` to see what it looks like.